# Passing ListView item clicked between activities

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I have a list view on my main activity that gets its data from a database.

The issue I'm having is passing the text to the next activity based on what the user selected on the list.

I am getting the list view to open the next activity and to send some weird string to the next activity, but it's not the right info being sent. Here is my code:

**MAIN ACTIVITY CODE:**

```
package com.example.chris.gymtracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class Days extends AppCompatActivity {
    dbAddDays dbAddDays;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_days);
        dbAddDays = new dbAddDays(this);
        final ListView daysListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.daysListView);
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{dbAddDays.ADDDAYS_KEY_DAYS};

        Button addDaysButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDaysButton);
        Button refreshButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);

        addDaysButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent startAddDaysActivity = new Intent(Days.this, addDays.class);
                startActivity(startAddDaysActivity);
            }
        });
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                populateDaysListView();
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, fromFieldNames);
        daysListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        daysListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),selectWorkout.class);
                String s = daysListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                myIntent.putExtra("itemSelected",s);

                startActivityForResult(myIntent,position);
            }
        });
    }
    public void populateDaysListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbAddDays.getDaysData();
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{dbAddDays.ADDDAYS_KEY_DAYS};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.addDaysDaysTextView};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_add_day_text_view, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.daysListView);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

**SECOND ACTIVITY CODE:**

```
package com.example.chris.tracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class selectWork extends AppCompatActivity {
    dbAddDays dbAddDays;
    Days Days;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_work);
        Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
        //Bundle bun = intentExtras.getExtras();
        String s = intentExtras.getStringExtra("itemSelected");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText(s);
        dbAddDays = new dbAddDays(this);
        populateWorkoutGridView();
    }
    public void populateWorkGridView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbAddDays.getWorkoutData();
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{dbAddDays.ADDDAYS_KEY_WORKOUT};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.workoutWorkoutTextView};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_workout_text_view, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);
        GridView myGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.workoutGridView);
        myGrid.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

[Everything here works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n27Gj.png)

[But that bold Android. ... text view should show the text of the item clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJgmR.png)

Comment: You have two different adapters on the same listview. I'd suggest you stick with the CursorAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a CursorAdapter,  the getItemAtPosition call is returning the cursor object as seen by calling toString() on that object.

Try the code below.  It attempts to retrieve the cursor object and then grab the data by the column name from the fromFieldNames array.

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor)daysListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(fromFieldNames[column]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),selectWorkout.class);
myIntent.putExtra("itemSelected", fromFieldNames[position]);
startActivityForResult(myIntent,position);
```

Comment: @ChrisS My answer helps you ?

Comment: @ChrisS Accept my answer if it helps you.

Comment: this will not work and likely cause an array out of bounds exception.  fromFieldNames is a static array containing one element, if the user selects anything but the first row of data in the list, this will fail.

Comment: You passed the name of the column in the database, not the actual value